# QT-MSVC error C2248

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qwidget

I'm currently working on a gui using QT and MSVC 13 compiler.
Whilst setting up a grid I have an error with QWidget

```
C:\Users\Gaz\Documents\CS22510\simsquare.h:15: error: C2248: 'QWidget::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QWidget'
```

in the header file

```
#ifndef SIMSQUARE_H
#define SIMSQUARE_H

#include <QWidget>


class SimSquare : public QWidget
{
     Q_OBJECT
public:
    SimSquare(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~SimSquare();
protected:
    void PaintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
};

#endif // SIMSQUARE_H
```

this is the cpp file

```
#include "simsquare.h"
#include <QtGui>


SimSquare::SimSquare(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    QPalette palette(Square::palette());
    palette.setColor(Qt::white);
    setPalette(palette);

}

void SimSqaure::PaintEvent(QPaintEvent *){
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setBrush(Qt::white, Qt::SolidPattern);
    painter.drawRect(10,15,80,90);
}

SimSquare::~SimSquare()
{

}
```

and this is referenced in

```
#include "simulation.h"
#include "ui_simulation.h"
#include <QVector>

Simulation::Simulation(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Simulation)  
{    
    simLayout = new SimBoard(this, 8);
    square = new SimSquare(this);
    for(int x =0; x<8; x++){
        for(int y =0; y<8; y++){
            //square = new SimSquare();
            squaresVec.append(&square);
            simLayout->add_widget(&square);
        }
    }
    this->setLayout(simLayout);
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

Simulation::~Simulation()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Thank you for any help that you may be able to give.

Comment: QObjects cannot be copied.

Comment: So where abouts am i doing that, Where I thought it might be is square = SimSqaure(this), but i'm doing the same with SimLayout which is a QGridLayout, and not getting any problems

Comment: Perhaps in the code we can't see.  I'm not sure either case of `&square` is correct though, it's already a pointer.  Did you really want 64 of the same object in your vector and layout?

Comment: Ahh that was advice from someone else. It's supposed to be creating an 8x8 grid, so the vector is being used so that I can reset each square of the grid easily when something changes. The code i've given is the only places that SimSquare is ever used currently

Comment: O also, square wasn't originally there, it was in the for loop, i forgot that i moved it to try and fix it

Comment: You should edit the code to be what it looks like when it gives you the error.  The line adding items to the vector looks wrong, but without the declaration it's hard to tell.  The line adding items to the layout is wrong, and it implies you may have been creating squares on the stack and then adding them to the vector as objects, not pointers which would cause the error.  Still, not enough code to spot the problem.  Start commenting things out and see when the error goes away.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71540/discussion-between-welsh4evr-and-retired-ninja).

Answer (score 0):

Okay solved that problem,

```
#include "simulation.h"
#include "ui_simulation.h"
#include "simsquare.cpp"
#include "simboard.cpp"
#include <QVector>
#include <QDebug>

Simulation::Simulation(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent),
    simui(new Ui::Simulation)
{    
    setupUI();
    this->show();
}

void Simulation::setupUI(){

    SimBoard simLayout(this,8);
    for(int x =0; x<8; x++){
        for(int y =0; y<8; y++){
            SimSquare square(this);
            squaresVec.append(&square);
            simLayout.add_widget(&square);
        }
    }
    this->setLayout(&simLayout);
    qDebug() << "Setting layout";
    simui->setupUi(this);
    qDebug() << "setu[ UI";

}
```

Basically because QWidget can't be copied rather than initialising it using = new, you create the object in the header file and then in the cpp call the constructor using Constructor objectname(parameters).

Just incase anyone else is having this problem.

Comment: You didn't solve anything.  The `SimSquare` you create on the stack goes out of scope 2 lines later and you have a dangling pointer in your vector.  The `SimBoard` also goes out of scope at the end of the function.